# index masking in matrix - matlab

Tags: matlab

I have matrix A and B

```
A = [NaN NaN 0 NaN 1 NaN NaN]
B = [0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
```

I want do a index masking, replace '0' with NaN by looking at matrix A index. How do script it so that my expected result would like this below.

```
C = [NaN NaN 1 NaN 0 NaN NaN]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put `NaN`s in `B` wherever `A` is `NaN`:

```
B(isnan(A)) = NaN;
```

This is sometimes called "logical indexing", and it's described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-3).